# javascript inherit from a class

Tags: javascript

Im learning inheritance. In the code below

1)penguin inherits from Animal

2)when I call penguin.sayName();  why does it output "Hi my name is undefined";

```
function Animal(name,numLegs){
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;


}
Animal.prototype.sayName = function(){
  console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
};


function Penguin(){}

Penguin.prototype = new Animal();

var penguin = new Penguin("Captain Cook", 2);
penguin.sayName();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `name` and `numLegs` properties to the penguin object via the function constructor.  These two properties are specific to the `Animal` object and will not be assigned simply by calling the Penguin constructor.

```
function Penguin(name,numLegs){
  this.name = name;
  this.numLegs = numLegs.
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/5A7hH/

You could also use the constructor on the prototype chain, which is similar to calls of the super() constructor in Java.

```
function Penguin(name,numLegs){
   this.constructor(name,numLegs);
}
```

Comment: thanks - but I still a little unsure, if its inheriting from Animal why don't those automatically get used?

Comment: @Hello-World It doesn't get used because the Animal constructor is never called unless explicitly stated, as illustrated in the second example.  In your example, the name and numLegs properties never get assigned since the Parents constructor is not called.  This is pretty standard in OO languages.  Are you familiar with Java?  Think about how the call to super is required for every class that extends another.

Comment: Not sure why but typically constructor will not get inherited by child object. This apply to C#, Java and etc.

Comment: Kevin Bowersox  - wow - thank you - I'm still new to all of this. which is the best way - Is your first example the most correct?

Comment: Please note that `this.constructor(name,numLegs);` *only* works because the `constructor` property is overridden to point to `Animal` in `Penguin.prototype = new Animal();`. *Usually* the `constructor` function points to the constructor function itself, i.e. to `Penguin`, so it does *not* behave like `super`. A better approach would be `Animal.apply(this, arguments)`.

Comment: @FelixKling  What if I added a function to Penguins prototype and call `this.constructor` from within said function, which constructor would I get?  I guess my question is when would I receive the child classes constructor when calling `this.constructor`?

Comment: @Kevin: As I said, *usually* `Constr.prototype.constructor` refers to `Constr` itself. And `this.constructor` would always point to `Constr` if the prototype wasn't overwritten completely, no matter *where* it is accessed. Often you will find the statement `Child.prototype.constructor = Child;` to "set things right again". Using `this.constructor` in *your* example is perfectly fine, however it might be confusing because of the already mentioned reasons... does this answer your question?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes it does. I appreciate the time you took to answer it.